# jQuery add image paths an style with href

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can some please advice how to add image path tp jQuery? Im trying to replace the coloured boxes in this script to actual real images, I've used C: for now as Im working locally.

Ideally I want to have 5 images appear one after the other on the screen, but then I want the images to be clickable and when clicked go to a specific URL.

Is this possible?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#div4").fadeIn(5000);
    $("#div5").fadeIn(7000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
   <body>
    <p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
    <button>Click to fade in boxes</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="div1">
        <img src="images/myimage1.png" alt="about" width="304" height="228"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <img src="images/myimage2.png" alt="about" width="304" height="228"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <img src="images/myimage3.png" alt="about" width="304" height="228"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div4">
        <img src="images/myimage4.png" alt="about" width="304" height="228"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div5">
        <img src="images/myimage5.png" alt="about" width="304" height="228"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML above is invalid... missing img tag and unclosed div. Can you clean it up first? Maybe stick it in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Nope still invalid (divs not closed on image lines). I will fix :)

Comment: agh thanks yes on same level need to be on next line, much thanks :)

Comment: ok, I see the images but they are there right away before I click the button?? they suppose to show after I click? ta

Comment: Do I need .hide on all divs? thanks

Comment: they did not need to be on the next line (just neater), you were missing the closing `>` on the divs. Re: `.hide`, you need to make them `display: none` via whatever means you like (class `.hide`) or just add the style `style="display: none"` to the divs directly.

Comment: agh of course I see the what you mean, that works adding to divs appear now after click, can now add a class to css. instead of fade in do you know a way to make the images animate say from left to right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use relative images paths.
create a directory structure for your project. For example c:\myProject. Add images directory into it (c:\myProject\images). Then you can use the paths like that:

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpeg" alt=""\>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I've realised I cant do locally, will do this, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can not get the images from your local path. As the browser will open from the client side. so you can not get the images from your local machine folder. You need to store the images on your server path and retrieve it from server path.

Create the folder in your project and store the images in that folder so that you can access it from your project when you up the server.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues to make this work as you outlined:

First (as mentioned by the other answers), you need to have your images in the project (e.g. relative paths which work locally and on the server).

Second, you did not provide any CSS, but to do a fade-in the divs need to be initially hidden.

Third, you can either change the `window.location` to go to another page from code, or just wrap your images in anchors. I have provided examples of each type on the following JSFiddle:

### JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nHk3k/4/

Which looks like this when I press the button:

[image]

If you don't use anchors you also want to have a hand cursor on the divs using both these styles (for cross browser support):

```
   cursor: pointer;
   cursor: hand;
```

Comment: Never used that tool, I tried going to but nothing happens when I click the button? I would style the css after I get the initial script working. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nHk3k/4/embedded/result/

Comment: @Dillon: What browser you using... it works fine in Chrome (will add screenshot)

Comment: Im using IE 8 I got it working locally now as you said, Ive commented above...strange thing though, when I click the button I see all the images for a very short period like a flash, then they disappear until I click the button and they fade in?

Answer (score 0):

Add a display:none style to your divs